# android - html5 localstorage issue

Tags: android, html, local-storage

While rendering HTML5 page in android where i had used localStorage of HTML5.

`localStorage["temp"] = "test";`

For above line it gives error: **TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'localStorage["temp"] = "test"')**.

(It works perfectly in browsers-chrome or firefox, In [html5 storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) page its written it supports android 2.0+)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting that to your webview settings :

```
yourWebViewObject.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: saurabh try like this localStorage.setItem("foo","thanks");
 alert(localStorage.getItem("foo"));thanks to christophecvb,it helps me